# how to code Python program to construct the following pattern, using a nested loop and conditionals

Tags: python, loops, nested

----Write a Python program to construct the following pattern, using a nested loop and conditionals?

```
***
*             *
*             *
*****
*             *
*             *
*             *------
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. Are there any rules to generating this pattern or are you just meant to hardcode it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems that you are asking someone to write code for you. Please, show your attempts and the specific part you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 3):

```
def print_pattern():
    for i in range(1000):
        for j in range(1000):
            if not i and not j:  # Question asks for conditionals, plural
                print("""***
*             *
*             *
*****
*             *
*             *
*             *------""")
                return None
```

Comment: if True: seems a little bit unnecessary there

Comment: @rv.kvetch The question asked for nested loops and a conditional. `if True` is a conditional

Comment: right, but i mean it's completely pointless. i can't imagine I would use if True: in any practical scenario, i mean.

Comment: I would argue that `if True` is the most readable conditional that would exactly satisfy this question. But yes, `if True` is otherwise pointless. Infact as this question asks for conditionals, it should be `if True and True`

Comment: correct, however if True and True is even more pointless. I think it could also be, if -1 or 0x1_234: also.

Comment: @rv.kvetch I have modified my answer for a better conditional at the expensive of increased complexity, however the algorithm is still O(1)

Comment: I would also add a `break` statement, just so that the script is indeed O(1) ;otherwise it looks good to me. Important thing here is you need **two** break statements (once in main loop) to completely break out of the nested loop, and hence achieve O(1) time.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Sorry you were right it was O(N^2) complexity, I refactored my code into a function and then used an early return if we have managed to do one iteration of the two for loops

Comment: totally forgot about the return statement, that's also a good way to break out early.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Ive done a lot of leetcode recently and is a useful pattern

Answer (score 2):

Simple O(n) solution with O(n) space.

```py
from base64 import b64decode

d = b'KiAgICAgICAgICAgICAq'
c = b'LS0tLS0t'
a = [b'Kioq'] +  [d]*2 + [b'KioqKio='] + [d]*3 

for i, f in enumerate(a):
    z = b64decode(f).decode("utf-8")
    for char in z:
        print(char, end='')
    if i != len(a)-1:
        print(b64decode(b'Cg==').decode("utf-8"), end='')
    if i == len(a)-1:
        print(b64decode(c).decode("utf-8"), end='')
```

Comment: upvoted for being the antithesis of the zen of python

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, 1 quick unit test and this is ready for prod.

Comment: pretty straightforward stuff. glad to know someone knows how to best approach a problem like this.

Comment: the single letter variable names are a bytecode level optimization. Helps them fit in l1 cache better I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
# first, our nested loop and conditional
for spam in "eggs":
    for eggs in "spam":
        if spam and spam and eggs and spam:
            # I don't like SPAM!
            break

# next, our pattern
print("""
***
*             *
*             *
*****
*             *
*             *
*             *------
""".strip())
```